# Creating stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 with Begin and End

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SampleTable]
AS 
BEGIN
    BEGIN
    WITH 'Test' AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM dario1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM dario2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM dario3
    )
    END 

    IF select Column1 = 1 FROM Test
    BEGIN
      --another commands.. etc..
    END

    IF select Column1 = 2 FROM Test
    BEGIN
         --another commands.. etc..
    END

    IF select Column1 = 3 FROM Test
    BEGIN
         --another commands.. etc..
    END
END
```

Please don't bother with my codes, this is only just a sample.

My questions are: do the `BEGIN` and `END` help to optimize the memory consumption? Even if I have 3 tables and my records are about millions?

I am still confused using `BEGIN` and `END`.

Any answer will be appreciated.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**BEGIN and END** are similar to the open braces and closing braces in C# ({}) **used to indicate logical code blocks**. It doesn't affect memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

No, as per [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189079%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), `BEGIN` and `END` are control-of-flow language keywords. Those are only used to indicate logical code blocks, not memory consumption models. On the same note, those also don't affect atomicity of your transactions.

Comment: thanks for your comment bro, So basically the optimization of memory will depends to your query and index?

Comment: @dario Correct, among other things

Comment: @dario if you find one of the answers acceptable please feel free to upvote or mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

No,  BEGIN and END have nothing to do with the memory consumption. Its just a logical block used to group different SQL statments

Comment: any suggestion to optimize the memory consumption? thanks bro